# Regex - dealing with parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting better at regex, but I'm still having some trouble... I'm trying to extract a value from inside of a set of parentheses using regex. The problem I am having is when this set is preceded by an open parenthesis.

Here are some examples:

```
'x(1)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/)[1] // returns "1" as expected
'\)(1)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/)[1] // returns "1" as expected
```

The character before parentheses can be anything, including another open parenthesis

```
'\((1)'.match(/\((.+?)\)/)[1] // returns "(1", but I only want "1"
```

This is only a snippet of the string, so this portion is already split out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Never use the dot when there is a more precise expression: `[^()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that data set, the easiest thing to do would probably just be to add a quantifier to the open paren, eg:

`/\(+(.+?)\)/`

This way it matches any consecutive number of open parens leading up to what you want to capture, but must at least have one paren immediately preceeding the next part of the match. Example on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/RiiQqqSlbl) here. **Note though**: As I allude to below, this will capture open parens within the grouping that are delimited by other characters (ridgerider provides an example with `( (stuff))` in the comments below, similar would be something like `(1(1)`. *It is not explicitly clear from your sample if this is desired behavior*, but if not then see below.

Operating under the assumption that you aren't going to need to capture a `(` anywhere (i.e. you only want the innermost matching parens), you can explicitly make sure you don't match the `(` character anywhere in your group if you use `[^(]+?` instead of `.+?`. It's certainly a more strict alternative, though. You can see that one on rubular [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/Fxfbub7YA3). To reiterate, though: this wouldn't allow the `(` character *anywhere* within the group, which may or may not be valid in other data you're working with beyond this sample. You could also further refine this to `[^()]+`. The full regex would then be either `/\(([^(]+?)\)/` or `/\(([^()]+)\)/` (I believe these are semantically equivalent, but I probably haven't covered all corner cases, the latter is the "safest" by means of being the most strict).

Comment: Does not work. `/\(+(.+?)\)/` erroneously matches: `(stufff))))`.

Comment: @ridgerunner: It doesn't capture `stufff)))` if that's what you mean. It will match, but only capture `stufff`. I have no idea if the OP wants to match `(stufff))))` and capture the interior, though.

Comment: @ridgerider: Per your comment pre-edit: You are correct. I intended the top half of the answer to cover his sample without making any further assumptions about his data, meaning that `( (stuff)` or any derivation (maybe `(1(1)`) would all work. The bottom half was intended to be aimed at the (probably more likely) scenario where `(1(1)` should return simply `1`. I've edited my answer to try to make that much more clear.

Comment: I don't need to worry about more closing parenthesis, so the regex you provided is working just fine :)

Answer (score 6):

Never use the dot when there is a more precise expression. In this case you are looking to match the contents of an innermost parentheses. The contents are thus, any characters which are not open or closing parentheses like so:

`/\(([^()]+)\)/`

Comment: +1 for the right answer. I would use the `*` quantifier instead, tells the caller indeed there was an inner parentheses as well, even if nothing is in it... if thats important.